# SQL Server trigger : delete duplicate then Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

Hello I am trying to create a history table.. My code pretty much works fine but my reports' queries compute for the summation of rows with the same column value (x_id)

Now I would like to create a trigger that would first DELETE the old rows
(For instance, row 1's value is (5x,100))

Then my trigger would insert (5x, 200), (5x, 300)

I would like to delete first the (5x, 100) column before inserting my (5x, 200) and (5x, 300)

I tried putting a `DELETE` statement before my `INSERT` in my trigger but I end up with just 1 row inserted on my history table, it deletes also the newly added rows except for the last row..

If it matters, my trigger is `AFTER UPDATE` and `DELETE`.

Also, `table1` and `table1_hist` have the exact same column definition.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER trig_table1_hist
 ON table1
 AFTER UPDATE, DELETE
 AS
     DELETE FROM table1_hist 
     WHERE table1_hist.t_id IN (SELECT t_id FROM inserted)

     INSERT INTO table1_hist 
        SELECT * 
        FROM inserted
```

I tried this but it deletes the newly added rows too with the same primary key. Now If i don't delete, my table would then have (5x,100) (5x,200) (5x,300) But I need the (5x,100) to be disappeared because my reports would still include the (5x,100)

Comment: Please post your attempted trigger code.  It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do or what you've attempted and is going wrong here.

Comment: @DanField There. I tried to make a similar code to what I am using. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need logic to check whether it was an `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.  Delete will use the psuedo-table `deleted` rather than `inserted`.  For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_table1_hist
  ON table1
  AFTER UPDATE,DELETE

 AS
 IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 from deleted))
 BEGIN
    DELETE FROM table1_hist where table1_hist.t_id IN (SELECT t_id FROM   deleted)
    INSERT INTO table1_hist 
    SELECT * FROM deleted
ENd

IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted))
 BEGIN
    DELETE FROM table1_hist where table1_hist.t_id IN (SELECT t_id FROM   inserted)
    INSERT INTO table1_hist 
    SELECT * FROM inserted
ENd
```

Aside from that, you need to make sure you're using a unique key - pick the **primary key** for table1, don't use a field that may or may not repeat - otherwise, you'll end up with unintended consequences (like putting the wrong row(s) into the history table).

Comment: Will the script only delete the old values and retain all newly inserted rows? Because I can add multiple rows here.. Oh and if i decide to also add the trigger on insert, will this still work? Currently downloading sql on home and will try in a few minutes. Thanks.

Comment: In my own testing (without any computed columns, which you might be using?), this worked fine.  It should work after insert as well.  The idea is that tmp_hist will contain the __last__ inserted/updated/deleted value(s).  However, if you have both insert and update, you probably don't need delete.

Comment: I tried this but the last inserted row is left.. For instance orig row is 5x,100
Then I inserted 5x,200 and 5x,300 (Together, at the same time)
The idea is to have the 5x,200 and 5x,300 inserted both on my history table.

Comment: It is generated after the row undergoes through a process. The row can exist on the original table even though t_id's value is null. It only gets a value afterwards. Now I am saving these rows on my history table where t_id has a value. I would like to give out my table definition but I do not have them with me at home.

Comment: There's your problem.  Use a unique key to do this.  I had been assuming t_id was the primary key of the row(s).  Editing answer to clarify.

Comment: Oh okay.. Problem is there's a scenario where t_id may be inserted into my history table and then it is used again on the original table.. Also the row can have different t_id's on different times. (--> t_id got a value, got cancelled then t_id is '' again -> t_id gets a new value)

Comment: You can have the t_id field on both tables, but you should not be using it as the lookup key if it's not unique. Instead, use the primary key from `table1`.

Comment: Oh okay thanks. Will just try stuff again tomorrow when I get to work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably inserting 2 rows in table 1 so your trigger is triggered 2 times (the first one deletes (5x,100) and the second deletes (5x,200))

I don't know in which scenario are you, but I would recommend to add a column with the date you inserted the data in you table1_hist and show reports according to those dates. Deleting rows in a history table is usually bad idea

Comment: I tried to add a date column but the rows do not have the same date value down to the milliseconds. I used the getdate()